# Will Agent Coulson ever be in a Marvel movie again?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

Joss Whedon stated that Agent Coulson will "remain dead" for *Avengers: Age of Ultron*. However, with the strong tie-in between *Agents of SHIELD* and the movies, is there any information if Agent Coulson will return to cinema in the future (for example in the upcoming *Avengers: Infinity War*)?

I'm not asking for speculations. I just found it curious that Joss Whedon said, that Coulson will remain dead "for *Avengers: Age of Ultron*", instead of saying "for the rest of the Marvel Cinematic Universe".

Comment: I've voted to close this as primarily opinion based - we simply have no idea about the plans for the character moving forward beyond the obvious *Agents of SHIELD* season 3. That being said, the in fighting between the Marvel Studios film and TV departments makes it seem unlikely, at least to me.

Comment: Will he ever be in a Marvel movie again? NOT WHILE I BREATHE

Comment: @DrRDizzle: “the in fighting between the Marvel Studios film and TV departments” — that kind of sounds like the start of a reasonable answer! You *tease*.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite But it's based on rumours about tensions at a corporate level. For all I know, Joss Whedon's departure from the MCU means that the Russo Brothers are the go to guys - and they may be itching to have Coulson cameo in *Captain America: Civil War* or *Avengers: Infinity War*. The problem is that until someone announces Coulson's appearance in a film, we have nothing but speculation to go on.

Comment: @DrRDizzle: gotcha. If they were rumours with reasonable sources, I reckon it’d be fine. I do know what you mean though, any speculation about future works is a bit of an invitation to discussion and a huge mess.

Comment: "until someone announces Coulson's appearance in a film" - That's what i'm asking, if that has happened in any small interview or something.

Speculation is not my intention.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Well then as of right now, no. Clark Gregg (the actor who plays Agent Coulson) has not been cast in any Marvel Cinematic Universe films currently in production. That being said, thanks to the events of the show Coulson now has the potential to be involved in a number of Marvel Cinematic Universe movies, including *Captain America: Civil War* and *The Inhumans*.

Comment: Well, what a bummer :\ If you rewrite that comment as an answer, i can select it as answer.

Comment: Also consider that the movies are made for a much bigger audience. Movie makers cannot assume anyone has seen Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. If they do bring Coulson back, they would have to explain (in the movie) why he's not dead. The TV-shows are in the same continuity, but the connectedness is a one-way street, at least up until now. It's not impossible: the Defenders are rumoured to be in Avengers: Infinity War, so Coulson could return to the movie-part of the MCU.

Comment: Yes. He's slated to appear in Captain Marvel. But that's kind of cheating, since that takes place in the 90's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of right now, no. Clark Gregg (the actor who plays Agent Coulson) has not been cast in any Marvel Cinematic Universe films currently in production despite his continued appearance in the Marvel Cinematic Universe through the TV show *Agents of SHIELD*.

That being said, thanks to the events of the show Coulson now has the potential to be involved in a number of Marvel Cinematic Universe movies, including *Captain America: Civil War* and *The Inhumans*, so who knows.

Answer (score 1):

When Joss Whedon was in charge like you said there was never going be a Coulson, but now that he is not longer attached to the Avengers movies who knows.

Coulson is definitely a fan favourite, which is why he was put on Agents of Shield. I wouldn't be surprised if he starts appearing again to tie tv and movies closer together since Joss isn't there to stop it.

It really makes a lot of marketing sense to have more crossover with tv and movies like the way Winter Solider really had an impact on the show, while Age of Ultron was barely a passing remark and had essentially no impact.